# How can I remotely participate in the UDS?

Tags: uds

How can I participate remotely in the upcoming UDS? Someone wrote an excellent article for remote participation for UDS-N but I couldn't find any information for the coming summit.

Any information and links will be helpful. Also last time It was advised to use Gobby Notes but I totally failed to connect to any server. Is there an alternative for Gobby Notes or some other way to read logs of UDS sessions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to find all the information you need to remotely participate here:

http://uds.ubuntu.com/participate/remote/